# Blazor CSS isolation bundling results in incorrect scope identifiers when building & deploying with Azure Pipelines

Tags: c#, css, azure-pipelines, blazor

My question in short:  Why would Azure Pipelines incorrectly append CSS scoped identifiers, for some components with CSS isolation?

> ****Update**   The only way I managed to fix this issue, was the create a new Blazor Server .NET6 app from scratch, copy all my
> code from the old app, and create a new repository.  There are no differences made to the code, but
> now the pipeline builds without any issues, and isolated CSS bundling
> works 100%.  However, I still have no idea what caused this issue in the first place, and
> how to prevent/fix it in future.

When building locally, or using right-click publishing, my .NET 6 Blazor Server App's bundled CSS file `{assembly}.styles.css` works 100%.  However, when using Azure Pipelines to create an artifact and publish to my App Service, I realised that the scope identifiers for some components are incorrect.  For instance, the scoped identifiers for my MainLayout.razor component matches, but for some reason the scoped identifiers for NavMenu.razor are incorrect (and the NavMenu scoped CSS values have no impact at all).

The process of CSS isolation bundling is explained in [MS Docs.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#css-isolation-bundling)

Example of incorrectly appended scope identifiers:

***CORRECT* CSS File in Local/Right-click publish WebApp:**

```
.NavBar[b-mdlfcd8dd5]
{
    color: white !important;
}
```

***INCORRECT* CSS file in WebApp published by Azure Pipeline**

```
.NavBar[b-snwh2aemf5] {
    color: white !important;
}
```

You'll note that the b-[xxxxxxxxxx] values are different.  If I use DevTools to replace the 10-string characters from bottom code, with those in the top, the CSS works in my app deployed from the pipeline. Therefore, my only conculsion is that somehow Azure Pipelines appends the incorrect scope identifiers during bundling. Building, or publishing directly from VS2022, bundles the CSS with the correct identifiers for all components - I only have the problem when the build happens in Azure Pipelines, and only a few components have this issue.

My Azure Pipeline is as follows - however I feel sceptical that the fault is within the pipeline - as some components have no problem:

```
trigger:
- master
variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Debug'
  dotnetSdkVersion: '6.x'
  releaseBranchName: 'master'

schedules:
- cron: '0 3 * * *'
  displayName: 'Deploy every day at 3 A.M.'
  branches:
    include:
    - master
  always: false 


stages:
- stage: 'Build'
  displayName: 'Build the web application'
  jobs:
  - job: 'Build'
    displayName: 'Build job'
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest

    steps:
    - task: UseDotNet@2
      displayName: 'Use .NET SDK $(dotnetSdkVersion)'
      inputs:
        packageType: sdk
        version: '$(dotnetSdkVersion)'

    - script: 'echo "$(Build.DefinitionName), $(Build.BuildId), $(Build.BuildNumber)" > buildinfo.txt'
      displayName: 'Write build info'
      workingDirectory: MyAppName/wwwroot

    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
      displayName: 'Restore project dependencies'
      inputs:
        command: 'restore'
        projects: '**/*.csproj'

    - template: Templates/build.yml
      parameters:
        buildConfiguration: $(buildConfiguration)

    - publish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifact: drop

- stage: 'Dev'
  displayName: 'Deploy to the dev environment'
  dependsOn: Build
  condition: |
    and
    (
      succeeded(),
      eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], variables['releaseBranchName'])
    )
  jobs:
  - deployment: Deploy
    pool:
      vmImage: windows-latest
    environment: dev
    variables:
    - group: Release
    strategy:
      runOnce:
        deploy:
          steps:
          - download: current
            artifact: drop
          - task: AzureWebApp@1
            displayName: 'Azure App Service Deploy: website'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: 'Resource Manager - MyAppName - Dev'
              appName: '$(WebAppNameDev)'
              package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(buildConfiguration)/*.zip'
```

Comment: I got similar problem before that the identifier generated is not as expected. It turns out if it was ordinary html tag, it generates correct identifier. When it is a MudBlazor component, the identifier will wrong. So I have to either put the style in app.css or not using Mudblazor component with isolation.

Comment: @MasterWil - thank you very much for the tip.  Just FYI: I am not using any 3rd party components.  I just added a small "test" component, included it in my Index.razor, and added a small isolated css file to change font color - but this still results in the same issue :-| But I'll watch this space - , maybe someone else had this issue with their components too...

Comment: If you have a GitHub account, you may try `uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1` instead of `UseDotNet@2`, to pinpoint the problem is on the pipeline side.